# Flutter error: Null check operator used on a null value - ChangeNotifierProxyProvider issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-change-notifier

I am new to `Flutter` and this is my first time using `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` following YouTube tutorial. I did the exact way it was done but I got this error in vs code.
Is there anything I missed or I am doing it wrong. Please help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Error
`Null check operator used on a null value`

main.dart

```
 MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => AuthProvider(),
        ),
        //send the value of user form authProvider to booking provider
        //error here.
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<AuthProvider, BookingProvider>(
          create: (_) => BookingProvider(),
          update: (_, authProvider, bookingProvider) => bookingProvider!
            ..loadUser(authProvider.getUser!), 
        )
      ],
```

booking_provider.dart

```
class BookingProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;

  void loadUser(User user) {
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

auth_provider.dart

```
class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;
  String _docUser = '';
  User? get getUser {
    return _user; // user has value
  }
}
```

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building _InheritedProviderScope<BookingProvider?>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<AuthProvider?>], value: Instance of 'BookingProvider', listening to value):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<AuthProvider, BookingProvider>
package:queuems/main.dart:64
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      MyApp.build.<anonymous closure>
package:queuems/main.dart:67
#1      new ListenableProxyProvider.<anonymous closure>
package:provider/src/listenable_provider.dart:123
#2      _CreateInheritedProviderState.build
package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:839
#3      _InheritedProviderScopeElement.build
package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:539
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4588
#5      _InheritedProviderScopeElement.performRebuild
package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:495
#6      Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4311
#7      BuildOwner.buildScope
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2578
#8      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:882
#9      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:363
#10     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1145
#11     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1082
#12     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:996
#16     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:150:10)
#17     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:270:5)
#18     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:114:31)

(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (21019): {status: true, message: Successful login, user: Instance of 'User'}
E/flutter (21019): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter (21019): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
E/flutter (21019): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
E/flutter (21019): #0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3990
E/flutter (21019): #1      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4004
E/flutter (21019): #2      Element.findRootAncestorStateOfType
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4064
E/flutter (21019): #3      Navigator.of
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:2546
E/flutter (21019): #4      LoginBody.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:queuems/…/login/login_body.dart:163
E/flutter (21019): #5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
E/flutter (21019): #6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter (21019): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21019):
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying get a user (`authProvider.getUser!`) when user variable doesn't initialized. By default, `_user` variable is `null`, and when you get it by `getUser` in `loadUser` it is still `null`. You can initialize this value in other place (load from database or other source).

Answer (score 0):

```
 ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<AuthProvider?, BookingProvider?>(
          create: (_) => BookingProvider(),
          update: (_, authProvider, bookingProvider) => bookingProvider!
            ..loadUser(authProvider.getUser!), 
        )
```

Use this

Comment: I am also facing the same problem I had tried your solution but the result is same